# Magento - Redirect to checkout success page from controller not working

Tags: php, magento, redirect

I google it everywhere but didn't get any help I want to redirect to success page after saving order.I am using 
Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::_redirect('checkout/onepage/success', array('_secure'=>true)) in my payment controller. Here is my code.

```
    public function responseAction() 
      {
         $data = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        if ($data['data']){
            $quoteObj = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($data['data']);
            $quoteObj->assignCustomer(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer());

            $quoteObj->collectTotals()->getPayment()->setMethod('payme');
            $quoteObj->collectTotals()->save();

            //Feed quote object into sales model
            $service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $quoteObj);        
            //submit all orders to MAGE
            $service->submitAll();
            //Setup order object and gather newly entered order
            $order = $service->getOrder();          
            //Now set newly entered order's status to complete so customers can enjoy their goods. 
            $order->setStatus('complete');
            //Finally we save our order after setting it's status to complete.
            $order->save();
            Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::_redirect('checkout/onepage/success', array('_secure'=>true));

}
```

Comment: `$this->_redirect('checkout/onepage/success'` should work exactly as you want.  You haven't suggested what happens currently?  Do you get redirected somewhere, or stay at module/something/response/?

Comment: I have also tried this. Currently it's not redirecting anywhere what I can see in console is
POST http://xxx/modulename/payment/response
GET http://xxx/modulename/checkout/onepage/success
GET http://xxx/modulename/checkout/cart

Answer (score 0):

What class is your controller extending? */app/code/community/Phoenix/Moneybookers/controllers/ProcessingController.php* and */app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/controllers/StandardController.php* seem to be doing something similiar to what you are trying to accomplish; take a look at their source. They both extend **Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action**. Try extending the Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action class in your controller and using

> $this->_redirect('checkout/onepage/success', array('_secure'=>true));

instead of

> Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::_redirect('checkout/onepage/success', array('_secure'=>true));

In other words, don't call the _redirect method as a static method, but from within the controller itself.

Comment: My class is extending  Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action like this below 
class Meigee_Payme_PaymentController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action and I tried $this->_redirect('checkout/onepage/success', array('_secure'=>true)); but still no success.

Answer (score 0):

you can try Mage::getUrl($route, $params);

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to load the session and set some required parameter. Otherwise you'll be redirected to the cart as you can see in `Mage_Checkout_OnepageController::successAction()`

**Try**

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/type_onepage')->getCheckout();

$quoteId = $reorder->getQuote()->getId(); // just an example
$orderId = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->getCollection()->getLastItem()->getEntityId()
$incrementId = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->getCollection()->getLastItem()->getIncrementId();


$session->setLastSuccessQuoteId($quoteId);
$session->setLastQuoteId($quoteId);
$session->setLastOrderId($orderId); // Required, otherwise getOrderId() is empty on success.phtml
$session->setLastRealOrderId($incrementId);

// Now the redirect supposed to work
$this->_redirect('checkout/onepage/success', array('_secure'=>true));
```